# Jupyer doesn't recognize uncertainties library

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, installation

I have to solve an exercise where I use uncertainties and after doing some research I noticed that I have to use the uncertainty library, but jupyter (which is where I practice python) doesn't recognize the library, for example, I try to import "from uncertainties import ufloat" and jupyter gives "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'uncertainties'".
What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package using

```
conda install -c conda-forge uncertainties
```

If you are performing the conda install in some environment you must install ipykernel to use the environment in your jupyter notebook. By following this link

https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html